# How does this proof of Fibonacci work

Tags: golden-ratio

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{i+1}&=&F_{i} + F_{i-1}\\
&=&\frac{\phi^i-\hat{\phi^i}}{\sqrt5}+\frac{\phi^{i-1}-\hat{\phi^{i-1}}}{\sqrt5}\\
&=&\frac{\left(\phi+\hat{\phi}\right)\left(\phi^i-\hat{\phi^i}\right)-\phi\hat{\phi}\left(\phi^{i-1}-\hat{\phi^{i-1}}\right)}{\sqrt5}\text{(Why does this work?)}\\
&=&\frac{\phi^{i+1}-\phi\hat{\phi^i}+\hat{\phi}\phi^i-\hat{\phi^{i+1}}-\phi^i\hat{\phi}+\phi\hat{\phi^i}}{\sqrt5}\\
&=&\frac{\phi^{i+1}-\hat{\phi^{i+1}}-\phi\hat{\phi^i}+\phi\hat{\phi^i}-\hat{\phi}\phi^i+\hat{\phi}\phi^i}{\sqrt5}\\
&=&\frac{\phi^{i+1}-\hat{\phi^{i+1}}}{\sqrt5}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

How to does the following become simplified?

$\frac{\phi^i-\hat{\phi^i}}{\sqrt5} =\left(\phi+\hat{\phi}\right)\left(\phi^i-\hat{\phi^i}\right)$

$\frac{\phi^{i-1}-\hat{\phi^{i-1}}}{\sqrt5} = \phi\hat{\phi}\left(\phi^{i-1}-\hat{\phi^{i-1}}\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\hat{\phi} = - \frac{1}{\phi}   \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad \hat{\phi} + \phi = 1$$

So multiplying by 1, won't change anything.

Above identities can be easily proven when you substitute:

$$\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad \hat{\phi} = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\phi$ and $\hat\phi$ are the two roots of $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$. Explicitly,
$$\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2},\ \ \ \ \ \hat\phi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$$
Then it follows that 
$$\phi + \hat\phi = 1,\ \ \ \ \phi\hat\phi = \frac{1-5}{4} = -1$$